# How to import own components in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have got this file structure:

```
├── components
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── home.component.html
│   │   ├── home.component.js
│   │   ├── home.component.js.map
│   │   └── home.component.ts
│   └── spendings
│       ├── spendings.components.js
│       ├── spendings.components.js.map
│       └── spendings.components.ts
├── main.js
├── main.js.map
└── main.ts
```

`Spendings` component looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'spendings',
    template: 'This is text'
})
export class Spendings {
}
```

I want to import `Spendings` to `Home`.
So I put this line in `Home`:

`import {Spendings} from '../spendings/spendings.component';`

and of course:

`directives: [Spendings]` in a `Component` descriptor

`Home` eventually looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Spendings} from '../spendings/spendings.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './app/components/home/home.component.html',
    directives: [Spendings]
})
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

As a result I get:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module '../spendings/spendings.component'.`

From what I've read import path is relative to the file that the import is added to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK. Got it. It was a typo. I named my file spendings.component**s**.ts instead of spendings.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your file `spendings.components.ts` to `spendings.component.ts`